# Determine the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {1}{(n+1)!}$ using comparison test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {1}{(n+1)!}$$

I have seen examples where

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {1}{(n)!}$  is computed using $\frac {1}{(n)!} \le \frac {1}{2^n}$

but nothing like the original problem. I need help determining whether or not the series converges and diverges using the direct comparison test. I understand the ratio test is ideal for factorials but I can't use that. So what series do I compare it to and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well $\frac {1}{(n+1)!}\leq \frac {1}{n!}\leq\frac {1}{2^n}$, so you can follow the same reasonning.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that for $n>0$, $(n+1)!>(n+1)n=n^2+n>n^2$ so that $$\dfrac{1}{(n+1)!}<\dfrac{1}{n^2}$$
which is clearly convergent by the $p$-series.